# Cut Colour Out of Picture

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have pictures that present with black bars above and below the image:

[image]

The black bars are at a different height in the picture at different pictures. I want to remove the black bars from each picture and save a new picture to a folder. I googled a bit and found the following code (adapted for my needs).

Now, the problem is that the saved image still has the black bars. When I use getpixel to return the RGB value, it returns  it as 0,0,0. Does anyone have any ideas?

````
from PIL import Image, ImageOps
from os import listdir
from os.path import isfile, join
import numpy

mypath_cut = "Redacted Path to Image"
onlyfiles_cut = [f for f in listdir(mypath_cut) if isfile(join(mypath_cut, f))]

StimulusNumber = 0 
for image in onlyfiles_cut:
    im = Image.open('Cow Pictures/Cut Pictures/{}'.format(image)).convert('RGB')
    na = numpy.array(im)
    
    blackY, blackX = numpy.where(numpy.all(na==[0,0,0], axis = 2))
    
    top, bottom = blackY[0], blackY[-1]
    left, right = blackX[0], blackX[-1]
    
    ROI = na[top:bottom, left:right]
    
    StimulusNumber += 1
    Image.fromarray(ROI).save("Cow Pictures/Cut Pictures/Cut_NoBlack/Cow{}.jpg".format(StimulusNumber))```
````

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This code may help you out.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from PIL import Image
image = np.array(Image.open("/Users/sohaibanwaartempr/Desktop/MCSTb.png").convert('RGB'))

# Mask of non-black pixels (assuming image has a single channel).
mask = image > 0

# Coordinates of non-black pixels.
coords = np.argwhere(mask)

# Bounding box of non-black pixels.
x0, y0, z0 = coords.min(axis=0)
x1, y1, z1 = coords.max(axis=0) + 1   # slices are exclusive at the top

# Get the contents of the bounding box.
cropped = image[x0:x1, y0:y1]
plt.imshow(cropped)
plt.show()
# crop_image(np.asarray(im),tol=0)
```

[image: Cow]

Comment: very nice solution +1; alternatively `mask = numpy.any(na!=[0,0,0], axis = 2)` to reduce the dimensions of coords a bit.